# List background color is showing black in dark mode

Tags: swiftui

I want to change the background colour of list view. I am showing the list view in dark mode, but every time the background color is black. Any suggestion to change the background colour?

```swift
GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                (colorScheme == .dark ? Color.SAColor.whiteWithAlpha10 : Theme.BackgroundColor.whiteBackgroundL2)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                    SaudiaNavigationView(viewModel: SaudiaNavigationViewModel(isHeaderPinned: false,
                                                                              title: "", shouldShowProfileDetails: false,
                                                                              showTitleAlways: false,
                                                                              showBackButton: false, normalLightColor: (colorScheme == .dark ? Color.SAColor.whiteWithAlpha10 : Theme.BackgroundColor.whiteBackgroundL2), normalDarkColor: (colorScheme == .dark ? Color.SAColor.whiteWithAlpha10 : Theme.BackgroundColor.whiteBackgroundL2),
                                                                              rightButtonType: .ImageButton(image: SAImageAssetConstants.flightDetailsCloseIcon, accessibilityText: "",
                                                                                                            buttonAction: {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }),
                                                                              imageButtonAccessibilityLabel: Accessibility.close))
                    .frame(height: 34 + geometry.safeAreaInsets.top)
                    List {
                        Section {
}
                            .listSectionSeparator(.hidden)
                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)

                    }
                    .listStyle(.plain)
                    .padding(.top, -15)
                    .padding(.leading, -15)
                    .padding(.trailing, -15)
                    .padding(.bottom, -15)

                }.background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.SAColor.whiteWithAlpha10 : Theme.BackgroundColor.whiteBackgroundL2)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }.ignoresSafeArea()
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
```

All the nav bar and view list view will be a unique colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `List` has its own standard background.

Try setting `Color.clear` as the `.listRowBackground` on the `Section` inside the `List`. It might also help to hide the default list background using `.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)`:

```swift
List {
    Section {
        // List content
    }
    .listSectionSeparator(.hidden)
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    .listRowBackground(Color.clear) // <- ADDED
}
.listStyle(.plain)     
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden) // <- ADDED
```